# Are android handlers thread safe?

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-handler

I am doing some refactoring into an Android project. I have stumble upon a strange piece of code that I consider non thread-safe. Am I correct to think that this example could cause a random crash?

```
public class SampleClass
{
    Object foo = new Object();

    // foo can be set to null in the main thread

    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            if (foo == null)
                return;

            Thread.sleep(600,0);

            // There is a chance foo has been set to null while the thread was asleep...
            foo.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I hear that handler are thread safe by default, it seems that I would need to place synchronized blocks inside the handleMessage function and any place where foo could be set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Looper can deliver Message to handler only when thread is awake. 'foo' is a private field, and if you access it only from that method - that is fine