# Android Handler instance thread safety

Tags: java, android

Is Android `Handler` class instance itself thread safe?

For example, is it safe to post from multiple threads to the main thread with the example code below, or one has to instantiate two handlers (one in each thread)?

```
Handler singleHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Runnable runnable1 = new MyRunnable();
        singleHandler.postDelayed(runnable1, 100);
    }
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Runnable runnable2 = new MyRunnable();
        singleHandler.postDelayed(runnable2, 150);
    }
}).start();
```

There's a similar question on SO, but it deals with thread safety of message processing (not posting), which is slightly different [Are android handlers thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050358/are-android-handlers-thread-safe)

Comment: _Android Handler_ is "thread safe", although it isn't correct to apply the term here. _Handler_ is only responsible for "delivering" _Runnables_ and _Messages_ to a _Looper_, in your case the main _Looper_.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to docs to prove that it is indeed thread safe? Just to clarify: my question is specifically about thread safety of Handler itself. I.e.: is it safe to share one instance of Handler between two threads and call its `postDelayed` method from two threads in parallel. I would guess the answer is "yes", as it is probably only posting messages to Looper, but could not find any reputable source to back this assumption. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it completely fine to post from any numbers of `threads` to single instance of `Main` Handler. As @Onik mentioned Handler job is to deliver the message to mentioned `Looper`, and there is at any given time only one `MainLooper` for your process. So a single instance of handler will post to that. To support answer, if you look at `View.Java`, it initialises one `mHandler` inside `AttachInfo` and pretty much uses that to post all the messages to `MainLooper`.